What happens if I don't use a Schengen visa?
I received a Schengen tourist visa for about a month. If I can't use the visa, will it have any impact? Do I need to inform the embassy or anything? I am from India.

No, no one cares and there is no one to inform. Your getting of the visa doesn't obligate you in any way.

Thanks .. do you think it impacts when i apply visa for next time ?

@vivienplat No, and if anything, it is better for your character, as it shows you are not in rush to visit.

This doesn't matter for this trip. But in the future when you next apply, the consulate you apply to will review your travel history and they will see you did not do what you said you were going to do.
Not having travelled won't cause as much issue as if say you had travelled to a completely different country, but nevertheless you applied for a visa to go on a trip you provided evidence of, that you then did not do.
The problem you are starting to create is that historically you have provided an application with accommodation bookings flights etc...  and was not correct, this could be considered to have been misleading or inauthentic and so when you next apply this will (to an extent) mean the consular officer reviewing the documents may query the authenticity and veracity of the documents you have provided.
In practice this may have no affect, but combined with other factors within the application such as further discrepancies with previous Schengen visas or documents within the application materials could lead to further scrutiny and/or reduced visa validity.  I have seen applications refused outright due to previous travel in applications not being adhered to (in very extreme cases).
Essentially this is not a big issue on its own, but in combination with other factors could be.
The chosen answer here is incorrect as are the comments.  My answer is on the basis of having helped many people who have had visas refused or are living with consequences of poor travel history such as successive short validity visas.
Personally, I would err on the side of caution and when you next apply put in a short cover letter to explain why you secured a visa and didn't travel.  If there is a good reason for not using it then it will almost certainly be overlooked.  It is not worth reducing the quality of your next application, even if only slightly.

I agree but for short term visa India is not part of waiver program so basically we are too much restricted and in this case my leave are cancelled and i faced loss of money too.... there could be 100 of reasons for which u might not able to travel .
_ My answer is on the basis of having helped many people who have had visas refused or are living with consequences of poor travel history such as successive short validity visas  _ how u know this i am not sure they ever gonna tell u exact reason ?

There will be different reasons for cancelling a trip, my point being it is a good idea to tell then why so there are no questions.  I have been working on Schengen visas for 20 years, specifically the problem cases.  I am lucky enough to work with other Schengen professionals, lawyers and ex consular staff.  Also during this time the consulates have told us, sometimes very informative refusals and sometimes when we just asked them directly.  This along with the Visa code, the Common Consular Instructions from the EU and a lot of live case studies to refer to.
